# What is a regressive set?

Tags: definition, computability

Several authors (e.g. Jockusch, Appel, McLaughlin) use a notion of a **regressive set**, however none of the authors gives a complete definition, they refer to the paper *J. C. E. Dekker, Infinite series of isols, Proc. Sympos. Pure Math. Vol. 5, pp. 77-96, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, R. I., 1962.* in the volume http://www.ams.org/books/pspum/005/ to which I, unfortunately, do not have the access.

So what is a definition of a regressive set?

Comment: See Odifreddi vol. 1, [p. 238](https://books.google.com/books?id=ahBLqshTFMwC&pg=PA238) in the 2nd ed., 1999; there's in fact a whole section II.6 about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Respawned Fluff for pointing out a more accessible resource.

Definition II.6.2 (Odifreddi vol. 1): If $\{a_o, a_1,a_2,...\}$ is an enumeration without repetitions of $A$, and $\phi$ is a partial recursive function such that
$\phi(a_{n+1}) = a_n$ and $\phi(a_0) = a_0$,
then $A$ is called **regressive** via $\phi$ and with respect to the given enumeration.